# Boost::Process compile issues, had to modify lib to get it to work

Tags: c++, boost, process

So I downloaded the latest Boost::Process library and attempted to compile and I end up with this:

`libs/boost-1.55.0/build/include/boost/process/operations.hpp:85:36: error: ‘filesystem_error’ is not a member of ‘boost::filesystem’`

I did go ahead and check this file out, I removed that line (Along with the if statement ontop of it) and it compiles fine after the modification. The odd thing is that `filesystem_error` is in fact a member of `boost::filesystem` so I don't understand why it's complaining.

Is there any way to fix this without having to remove those lines? I really don't want to do a modification like that.

Here's the latest [Boost::Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process.zip) (I am using Boost 1.55.0 in case you wanted the version number).

Comment: Dont link to some "dubious" zip packages, include the code

Comment: Well right away doing `#include <boost/process.hpp>` causes a compile error.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix it like I did yesterday<sup>**[1]**</sup>:

In `boost/process/operations.hpp` change

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
```

into

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp> 
#include <boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp>
```

Or just

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

The reason appears to be that `path.hpp` no includes the header for the error class indirectly

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> okay, it was hidden in the ['amalgamate' on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be008d4602cdf1fb) :)

Comment: You are just too awesome. Thanks a million for all your answers!